# Determine the basetype of a type in UWP

Tags: reflection, types, uwp

I am developing a win 10 app. I would like to know the BaseType of a Type. How to do that using Reflection in uwp.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection in universal windows platform (UWP) missing properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068373/reflection-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-missing-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GetTypeInfo` extension method to get BaceType.

```
Type t = typeof(int);
Type baseType = t.GetTypeInfo().BaseType; // Returns System.ValueType
```